# Mathematical calculations using jQuery/Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

I have this in my Form

```
 <%= f.label :price, "price"%> 
<%= f.text_field :price, :size=>20, :id =>"price" %>

<%= f.label :quantity, "Quantity"%>
<%= f.text_field :quantity, :size=>20, :id =>"qty" %>

<%= f.label :amount, "Amount"%>
<%= f.text_field :amount, :size=>20, :id =>"amount"%>
```

I want {price*quantity} to happen inside the 'amount' field as soon as i enter values inside 'price' and 'quantity' i.e calculations should happen before submit. I am new to jQuery/Ajax, so any help will do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Yorgo ready learn ruby and you'll see HTML where you've never seen HTML.

Comment: @micha you can see created html in browser. For example in internet explorer you can see in Developer tools (F12)

Comment: @Yorgo yes but it's not needed because we've got ruby code. By the Way IE is a bad example.

Comment: @micha i asked for html codes because i dont know the ruby notation. So its needed for me and why IE is bad example?

Comment: @Yorgo Because the Developer tools of Chrome and Firefox are much better and btw even IE10 don't support the File API. So I don't recommend to use IE.

Comment: @micha its your opinion. i dont think so

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
$(function() {
    $("#price, #qty").keyup(function() {
        var p = $("#price").val();
        var q = $("#qty").val();
        $("#amount").val(q * p);
    });
});
```

But you have to give the amount field the id "amount" and not reuse "price" as the id.

Comment: I am getting 'NaN' in my amount field. Where m i going wrong?

Comment: Got it. had a spelling mistake and since i m using jquery i was advised to use `jQuery` instead of `$`. working wonderfully. :) Thanks alot mate..!!