# mathematical calculation using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

this question is not similar to 
[Mathematical calculations using jQuery/Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245216/mathematical-calculations-using-jquery-ajax)

so please downvoters.

i use two sets of radio buttons 
This fiddle i found shows the exact what i want
http://jsfiddle.net/8FXFE/6/

can i add another hidden sort of value to those buttons that i can use in any calculation?

HTML

```
<div class="textForm">
<input type="radio" name="txtNumber" value="100" checked="checked" />100
<input type="radio" name="txtNumber" value="200" />200
<input type="radio" name="txtNumber" value="500" />500
<input type="radio" name="txtNumber" value="1000" />1000
<input type="radio" name="txtNumber" value="10000" />10000
<input type="radio" name="txtNumber" value="other" />other
<input type="text" name="other_field" id="other_field" onblur="checktext(this);"
/>
</div>
<div class="formText">
    <input type="radio" name="txtSpace" value="RJ" checked="checked"
    />Space 1.
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="txtSpace" value="SM" />Space 2.
    <br />
</div>

<h3>Output:</h3>

<div id="output"></div>
```

like suppose i want to make the formula like this..

IF 100 IS SELECTED AND Space 1. IS SELECTED

then the formula shall go like this
hidden value of (name="txtSpace" value="RJ") + hidden value of (name="txtNumber" value="100")

can it be done? and if yes,, how?

Comment: _"can i add another hidden sort of value to those buttons that i can use in any calculation?"_ - Yes. Use html5-style `data-` attributes.

Comment: @nnnnnn can u show it updating that fiddle?

Comment: you cant hide anything in javascript as you can see everything in firebug.

Comment: Why don't you add this hidden value inside your function? For example If radio 100 is selected a = "hiddenValue1", else if rado 200 is selected a = "hiddenValue2" and so on... However it will be possible to see in Chrome console or Firebug as Sandeep Rao said.

Comment: @kmb is people can see that values in firebug or chrome.. is it possible for them to hack or change those values??

Comment: @Ashis Unfortunatelly I don't know if there is possible to hack this values, but if u press ctrl + shift + j in chrome you can see all java scripts or html rendered on your page

Comment: yes people can edit the values, that's what serverside validation is for

Comment: @DavidFregoli thankx fortunately i know to code in php and so i can solve this problem by server side validation... :)

Comment: **jQuery ALL the things**

Comment: Jquery ALL the things?

Comment: @AnaMaria: [Am I using too much jQuery? When am I crossing the line?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2826810)

Comment: @AnaMaria http://i.imgflip.com/2re2z.jpg

Answer (score 1):

try this script.just copy and paste this code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function fnc()
{
count1=document.getElementsByName("txtNumber").length;
count2=document.getElementsByName("txtSpace").length;
for(i=0;i<count1;++i)
{
    el=document.getElementsByName("txtNumber").item(i);
    if(el.checked)
        firstnumber=el.value;

}

for(i=0;i<count2;++i)
{
    el=document.getElementsByName("txtSpace").item(i);
    if(el.checked)
        secondnumber=el.value;

}
if(firstnumber=='100' && secondnumber=='RJ')
{
    alert("now you can write your formula here");
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need a function like this to keep track of the form values:

```
updateForm = function()
{
      var $txtNumber = $('[name=txtNumber]:checked'),
          $txtSpace = $('[name=txtSpace]:checked'),
          out = $txtSpace.val();

    if ($txtNumber.val() == 'other') {
        out += $('#other_field').val(); // use value of other_field
    } else {
        out += $txtNumber.val(); // use value from radio button
    }

    $('#output').text(out);
}
```

Then, to initialize:

```
updateForm();
$("input[name='txtNumber'],input[name='txtSpace']").change(updateForm);
```

Comment: Thats an interesting approach..
fiddle?

Comment: @ashis I will leave that up to you :)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<input data-fieldname="">
```

and jquery

```
$(this).data('fieldname')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FRu67/ <-- Tidied things up

- try avoiding input[name='txtNumber'] type selectors because they are among the slowest